# Java variable assignment

Tags: java

My code prints 0 instead of size and year. What am I doing wrong? Basically I want it to return those but I'm not sure what I'm doing.

```
public class House {
private int year;
private int size;
private static int nbrOfHouses; 
public static final int MIN_SIZE =10; 

public House(int _year,int _size){
    _year = year;
    _size = size;
}
public static int getNbrHouses(){ 
    return nbrOfHouses;
}
public int getYear(){
    return year;
    }
public int getSize(){
    return size;
}
}


House[] myHouse = new House[10];{
  myHouse[0] = new House(1902, 120);
  myHouse[1] = new House(1954, 180);
  myHouse[2] = new House(1995,90);

  for(int i=0; i< myHouse.length; i++){
        if(myHouse[i]!=null){
          System.out.println(myHouse[i].getYear());
```

Comment: you may also use advance for loop  for(House house: myHouse){
 System.out.println(house.getYear());

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is backwards:

```
public House(int _year,int _size){
    _year = year;
    _size = size;
}
```

Should be:

```
public House(int _year,int _size){
    year = _year;
    size = _size;
}
```

or better yet:

```
public House(int year,int size){
    this.year = year;
    this.size = size;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your constructor, you are not assigned the class variables correctly. Do this:

```
public House(int _year,int _size){
    year = _year;
    size = _size;
}
```

You're assigned the arguments to the class variables (which are initialized to 0). Since the class variables are initialized at 0 and are not modified, that's why it prints 0.

As mentioned by @pfrank, Java naming conventions don't usually have the underscore. A more conventional way to code it is with the `this` keyword.

```
public House(int year,int size){
    this.year = year;
    this.size = size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
public House(int _year,int _size){

this.year = _year;
this.size = _size;
}
```

Comment: that wont work, since the arguments of the constructor are `_year` and `_size`

Answer (score 1):

Fields are not initialized properly.

```
public House(int _year,int _size){
    this.year = _year;
    this.size = _size;
}
```

Comment: this.year = _year Careful of the argument name

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Language Specification section 15.26 states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)

```
AssignmentExpression:
    ConditionalExpression
    Assignment

Assignment:
    LeftHandSide AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression

LeftHandSide:
    ExpressionName
    FieldAccess
    ArrayAccess

AssignmentOperator: one of
    = *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= >>>= &= ^= |=
```

You always assign from the right hand side to the left hand side. This

```
public House(int _year,int _size){
    _year = year;
    _size = size;
}
```

is therefore reversed and should be

```
year = _year;
size = _size;
```

Also, because instance fields are by default initialized to 0 for primitive types, all your `int` fields have a value of 0.